# Trouble with Magma -- "Internal error in ff_degree()"

Tags: magma-ca

I have a question for the Magma users out there.

Occasionally I will write a program that will run for a little while before it is terminated with the following message:

> Internal error in ff_degree() at ff/access.c, line 1021

What does this mean?
Why does this problem only present occasionally?

Comment: This might be better reported to the Magma developers

Comment: @talonmies OK will do, thank you. I just thought I'd ask in case it was a common and/or easily fixable problem.